# Win32/C: Notepad wrapper that automatically converts Unix line endings to Windows line endings

Tags: c, strings, windows, winapi

At my work we're dealing with a lot of PHP files written by a third-party company and sometimes we want to "quickly look at" these files in Notepad rather than having to open up a full IDE.

The problem is that these files have `\n` line endings which as many of you know Notepad doesn't handle correctly. Sure, there are solutions like installing Notepad++ but everyone knows that the first rule of engineering is that you always reinvent the wheel every chance you get. I'm kidding, I just really like coding.

My solution: write a wrapper for Notepad that silently converts files containing Unix line endings into Windows/DOS style line endings and then opens the file in Notepad.

**Program Source Code:**

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

// Defines for the line-ending conversion function
#define LESTATUS INT 
#define LE_NO_CHANGES_NEEDED (0)
#define LE_CHANGES_SUCCEEDED (1)
#define LE_CHANGES_FAILED   (-1)

LESTATUS WINAPI ConvertLineEndings(BYTE *inData, INT inLen, BYTE *outData, INT outLen, INT *bytesWritten)
{
    INT sourceIndex = 0, destIndex;

    // Fail immediately; no chance of success here.
    if (outLen < inLen)
        return LE_CHANGES_FAILED;

    // Try to determine if changes are needed
    while (sourceIndex < inLen)
    {
        // If an \r is immediately followed by an \n, no changes are needed to inData.
        if (inData[sourceIndex] == '\r')
        {
            if (sourceIndex < inLen - 1 && inData[sourceIndex + 1] == '\n')
            {
                memcpy(outData, inData, inLen);
                *bytesWritten = inLen;
                return LE_NO_CHANGES_NEEDED;
            }
            // If we encountered an \r without a following \n then changes are needed.
            break;
        }

        // If we encounter an \n without a preceding \r then changes are needed.
        if (inData[sourceIndex] == '\n')
            break;
        sourceIndex++;
    }

    // But, up to the point where we encountered the bad line ending, we can copy *that* much into outData.
    memcpy(outData, inData, sourceIndex);
    // If, however, that was the end of the array, then we still don't need to make changes.
    if (sourceIndex == inLen)
        return LE_NO_CHANGES_NEEDED;

    // Now, we begin the actual copying/rewriting of the array, so set destIndex to sourceIndex to begin counting.
    destIndex = sourceIndex;

    // Loop through the remainder of inData; if an \n or \r is encountered, rewrite it as appropriate into outData.
    // If outData's limits are reached before we're done, report that changes failed.
    while (sourceIndex < inLen)
    {
        switch (inData[sourceIndex])
        {
        case '\n':
        case '\r':
            sourceIndex++;
            if (destIndex + 2 >= outLen)
                return LE_CHANGES_FAILED;
            outData[destIndex++] = '\r';
            outData[destIndex++] = '\n';
            break;
        default:
            outData[destIndex++] = inData[sourceIndex++];
        }
    }

    *bytesWritten = destIndex;
    return LE_CHANGES_SUCCEEDED;
}

INT APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, INT nShowCmd)
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    DWORD dwExit, dwHigh, dwLow, dwRead = 0, dwWritten = 0, dwLen;
    WCHAR *wszArgQuote = NULL;
    BYTE *bIn = NULL, *bOut = NULL;
    HANDLE hHeap = GetProcessHeap(), hFile;
    INT nWritten = 0;
    LESTATUS leResult;

    StringCchLength(lpCmdLine, STRSAFE_MAX_CCH, &dwLen);
    if(dwLen<=0)
    {
        MessageBox(0, L"No filename specified", L"Notepad Wrapper", MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP);   
        return 0;
    }

    hFile = CreateFile(lpCmdLine, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if(hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MessageBox(0, L"File not found or access denied", L"Notepad Wrapper", MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP); 
        return 0;
    }

    // HeapAlloc is most likely going to fail on a file > 2GB
    dwLow = GetFileSize(hFile, &dwHigh);
    if(dwHigh>0 || (dwLow&0x80000000)==0x80000000)
    {
        MessageBox(0, L"File is too large", L"Notepad Wrapper", MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP);   
        return 0;
    }

    bIn = (BYTE *)HeapAlloc(hHeap, HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, dwLow+1);
    // Worst case scenario: *every* character in the file is a newline - bOut must be at least double the size of bIn
    bOut = (BYTE *)HeapAlloc(hHeap, HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, (dwLow+1)*2);
    if(bIn==NULL || bOut == NULL)
    {

        MessageBox(0, L"Out of memory", L"Notepad Wrapper", MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP);
        return 0;
    }

    ReadFile(hFile, bIn, dwLow, &dwRead, NULL);
    leResult = ConvertLineEndings(bIn, dwLow, bOut, dwLow*2, &nWritten);
    if(leResult == LE_CHANGES_FAILED)
    {
        MessageBox(0, L"Could not convert line endings in file", L"Notepad Wrapper", MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP);  
        return 0;
    }
    // Reset file pointer so that we write the new data to the start of the file
    SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, 0, FILE_BEGIN);
    WriteFile(hFile, bOut, nWritten, &dwWritten, NULL);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    HeapFree(hHeap, 0, bIn);
    HeapFree(hHeap, 0, bOut);

    // Done converting file, now open it up in Notepad
    wszArgQuote = (WCHAR *)HeapAlloc(hHeap, HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, (dwLen + 10) * sizeof(WCHAR));
    if(wszArgQuote==NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(0, L"Out of memory", L"Notepad Wrapper", MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP);
        return 0;
    }

    // Surround filepath with quotes 
    StringCchPrintf(wszArgQuote, dwLen+10, L" \"%s\"", lpCmdLine);

    // Preparation & CreateProcess call
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));

    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);

    CreateProcess(L"C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe", wszArgQuote, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT | CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

    HeapFree(hHeap, 0, wszArgQuote);
    // Return notepad.exe's exit code
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &dwExit);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    return dwExit;
}
```

**Registry Changes**

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.php]
@="phpfile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\phpfile\DefaultIcon]
@="%SystemRoot%\\system32\\imageres.dll,-102"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\phpfile\shell\open\command]
@="C:\\Utilities\\npwrap.exe %1"
```

Any comments/suggestions for improvement?

Comment: Have you ever considered that WordPad, also included with all Windows versions, will handle \n endings just fine? :)

Comment: Is there any redistributable version of this for others to use? I am actually looking for the exact same thing now.

Comment: @meanbunny You could just compile this code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Architecture idea:

Code reads the entire file into memory, coverts it and then conditionally  writes it out.

```
ReadFile(hFile, bIn, dwLow, &dwRead, NULL);
leResult = ConvertLineEndings(bIn, dwLow, bOut, dwLow*2, &nWritten);
...
SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, 0, FILE_BEGIN);
WriteFile(hFile, bOut, nWritten, &dwWritten, NULL);
```

Consider an alternative that does not delete the original until the new one is *fully* created.  This avoids losing the file should *something* go wrong.  An additional benefit is no real CPU memory limitation.

```
open input for reading
open temp file output for writing
While reading a line of the file
  convert
  append to output
close input
close output (temp file)
rename input to temp file 2
rename temp file to original
delete temp file 2
```

---

If a non-zero length file does *not* end with `"\r\n"`, this is a condition that often causes trouble for various text based programs.  Consider an option to insure a final `"\r\n"`.

---

Robust code would check the result of file operations

```
// Missing check of return values.
ReadFile(hFile, bIn, dwLow, &dwRead, NULL);
...
SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, 0, FILE_BEGIN);
WriteFile(hFile, bOut, nWritten, &dwWritten, NULL);
CloseHandle(hFile);
```

---

Note that `"\n\r"`is translated into `"\r\n\r\n"` - Unlikely a major concern.

---

I found the excessive wide code unnecessarily challenging to follow.  Recommend to re- auto-format to the width of the presentation of this site.

```
CreateProcess(L"C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe", wszArgQuote, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT | CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

vs.

```
CreateProcess(L"C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe", wszArgQuote, NULL, NULL, FALSE,
    CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT | CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, 
    NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

---

Minor: Consider using the size of the object, rather than the supposed type of the object.  Less chance for error and easier maintenance.

```
// ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof si);
```